# How do I simulate array_agg(distinct x) over window?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a query that uses `array_agg` as a window function, i.e. with an `over (...)` clause. I'd like to get only the set of distinct values in this array aggregation, but this is not implemented as of Postgres 9.4:

For the following (simplified) query,

```
with test_data(day, daytime, song) as (
      select 'MON', 'morning', 'A'
      union all 
      select 'MON', 'morning', 'B'
      union all
      select 'MON', 'afternoon', 'A'
      union all
      select 'TUE', 'afternoon', 'B'
)
select distinct 
    day, 
    first_value(daytime) over w as started,
    array_agg(distinct daytime) over w as daytimes,
    array_agg(distinct song) over w as songs 
from test_data
window w as (partition by day order by daytime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

Postgres returns the following:

```
SQLERROR [0A00]: ERROR: distinct is not implemented for window functions
```

I am certain that I can't avoid the use of the window clause itself. How do I work around this limitation?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89031/using-distinct-in-window-function-with-over

Comment: So you want the songs to be both distinct and ordered by daytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the function [`anyarray_uniq`](https://github.com/JDBurnZ/postgresql-anyarray/blob/master/stable/anyarray_uniq.sql) as provided in this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/JDBurnZ/postgresql-anyarray). I wrapped the initial select in another `select`, applying `anyarray_uniq` and reusing all other columns as-is. Since this does exactly what I was looking for and luckily I do not need to consider performance in this case.